# R - Comparing datas of two data.frames with a loop, constant by constant

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, matrix

Basically, I want to compare the same constants (same [X,Y] values) from two data frames and applied them a few operations afterward, before stocking the result in a new data frame. The tricky part is that I need to treat all the values of these data frames.
In other words, I need to compare the value of dataA[1,1] with dataB[1,1] and if they respect certain conditions, I'll perform an operation, else another opeartion, then stock the result in a new data.frame.
After, rinse and repeat for dataA[1,2] and dataB[1,2] up to dataA[100,100] and dataB[100,100].

Obviously, I've to use a loop here (and some if/else), but I can't seems to figure out the proper structure.
Being used to php, I tried the *foreach* package in R, but it only return FALSE (and it do so in vector format instead of a matrix with multiple columns). If I do the operation by hand, there are more TRUE than FALSE, so obviously, something's wrong here :

```
 x <- foreach(dataIDH, dataPIB) %do% {
      if (dataPIB <= dataIDH+5 & dataPIB >= rankIDH-5) {
        x <- mean(dataPIB, dataIDH)
      } else { x <- FALSE}
    }
  x
```

I did tried a *for* loop, but I'm simply unable to put the results in a data.frame (even less a ones that match the layout of the dataframes used here, which I need to do) :

```
  x <-  for(idh in 1:nrow(dataIDH)) {  
    for(idh in 1:ncol(dataIDH)) { 

      for(pib in 1:nrow(dataPIB)) {   
        for(pib in 1:ncol(dataPIB)) { 

          if (pib<=idh+5 & pib>=idh-5) {
            x <- mean(pib,idh)

          } else { x <- FALSE}

        }
      }

    }
  }
x
```

For informations : the data frames contain numeric values for a set of countries (rows) for a few years (columns).

Any ideas on how to get out of this mess?

Edit 1 : an extract of the two dataframes used (1st row and col displayed here are actually headers) :

dataIDH

```
CountryCode,2005,2006,2007,2008
AFG,14,14,16,16
ALB,100,98,99,98
DZA,85,86,90,86
```

dataPIB

```
CountryCode,2005,2006,2007,2008
AFG, 69, 18, 70, 71
ALB, 102, 98, 97, 63
DZA, 85, 89, 91, 137
```

Edit 2 : and the final result should be a new data.frame, on the same layout:

x

```
CountryCode,2005,2006,2007,2008
AFG, FALSE, 16, FALSE, FALSE
ALB, 101, 98, 98, FALSE
DZA, 85, 87.5, 90.5, FALSE
```

Comment: It'd help if you share a sample of your data using `dput()`. Also I have a feeling that there's a better way to do this than looping through each cell.

Comment: You can also use functional programming for this. `map2_dfr()` from the [purrr][1] package might be something to look into.

If you provide a reproducible example, people will be able to help you through it. [This][2] might also help you get started.


  [1]: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/index.html
  [2]: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html

Comment: My bad for the lack of datas. It's corrected.

Answer (score 1):

With the basic looping way. Hope this helps you.

```
df <- dataIDH
for(i in 1:length(dataIDH$CountryCode)){
  for(j in 2:ncol(dataIDH)){
    if((dataIDH[i,j] <= dataPIB[i,j]+5) & (dataPIB[i,j] <= dataIDH[i,j]+5)){
      df[i,j] <-  mean(dataPIB[i,j], dataIDH[i,j])
    } else{ df[i,j] <- "False" }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Looks like I basically forgot to put nearly all the parameters in my code :/

Comment: Glad, you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a= rnorm(1000),
                  b=rnorm(1000),
                  c= rnorm(1000))
df2 <- data.frame(aa= rnorm(1000, 3, 3),
                  bb=rnorm(1000, -2, 3),
                  cc= rnorm(1000, 5, 3))

df3 <- data.frame(df1, df2)

test <- function(df, column_number1, column_number2){
  mean_vec <- apply(df[, c(column_number1, column_number2)], 1, function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
dif_vec <- abs(df[,column_number1]-df[,column_number2])
ind_true <- dif_vec<=5
ind_false <- dif_vec>5
column_name <- paste(colnames(df)[column_number1],
                     colnames(df)[column_number2], sep = "_" )
df[ind_true, (column_name)] <- mean_vec[ind_true]
df[ind_false, (column_name)] <- "FALSE"
return(df)
}

df3 <- test(df3, 1,4)
df3 <- test(df3, 2, 5)
df3 <- test(df3, 3, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't actually want to convert your data to strings (which would be necessary to include `"FALSE"` in a numeric vector), R is really good at working with vectors and matrices...

```
dataIDH <- read.csv(header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, text = "
CountryCode,2005,2006,2007,2008
AFG,14,14,16,16
ALB,100,98,99,98
DZA,85,86,90,86
")

dataPIB <- read.csv(header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, text = "
CountryCode,2005,2006,2007,2008
AFG, 69, 18, 70, 71
ALB, 102, 98, 97, 63
DZA, 85, 89, 91, 137
")

x <- abs(dataIDH[-1] - dataPIB[-1]) <= 5
y <- (dataIDH[-1] + dataPIB[-1]) / 2 
y[!x] <- NA
cbind(dataIDH[1], y)

# CountryCode X2005 X2006 X2007 X2008
# 1         AFG    NA  16.0    NA    NA
# 2         ALB   101  98.0  98.0    NA
# 3         DZA    85  87.5  90.5    NA
```